# Convert MyISAM to InnoDB in PXC master master

Tags: mysql, replication, clustering, percona, galera

I have 3 nodes PXC 5.6 master master cluster. I have few tables that are using MyISAM.

Total MyISAM table = 120
Total MyISAM table size = 80MB

I have also read few recommendations where it suggests not to run ALTER command on cluster.

How can I safely convert those tables to InnoDB without risking the cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comments on converting from MyISAM to InnoDB:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

My comments on Galera (PXC):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/galera

`ALTER`, on Galera/PXC, comes in two flavors;

```
⚈  Rolling Schema Upgrade = manually do one node (offline) at a time
⚈  Total Order Isolation = Galera synchronizes so that it is done at same time
     (in the replication sequence) on all nodes.
```

Further discussion (in addition to the manual, and my doc):  http://www.codership.com/wiki/doku.php?id=rolling_schema_upgrade

Comment: Nice documentation. Can you also please look at my another question?


[My question here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/225450/safe-backup-of-pxc-galera-cluster)